# How can I completely remove X-Windows from Fedora?

Tags: linux, yum, fedora, x11, remove

A while ago I installed my first Linux server using Fedora 10. I then upgraded to Fedora 11 and realized that I never use X-Windows on the machine, and during each update downloading a huge amount of files I don't need since everything on the machine is done remotely using ssh.

Using yum or any other tool, how can I completely remove Gnome and the X-Windows subsystem from this machine? Is the only alternative to do a complete re-install and not selecting X-Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove groups with yum.

```
yum groupremove "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

Use `yum grouplist` to see what groups you have installed.