# Strip X Window System from OpenRD (Fedora core 8)

Tags: fedora, x11, embedded

I just got myself an [OpenRD Client](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-openrdcdetails.aspx) embedded box with an old Fedora 8 on it. Runs like a charm, only problem is that the default install has X on it, which I would like to remove in order to free up some space.

I found a [similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/63159/how-can-i-completely-remove-x-windows-from-fedora) here on the same topic, but `yum groupremove` doesn't work in my case, `yum grouplist` returns nothing, so I presume that no groups are defined. I don't know if this is because fedora 8 didn't have any groups, or because the OpenRD build is special in some way.

In any case, I would like some tips on which package(s) to remove in order to remove an as big chunk of X as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planning on using it as a router or some such?  It looks like a really clever little box.  What about using an SD card?  They're cheap and it seems to support them.

Comment: I'll be using it as a general server - file sharing, scm etc for personal use. I used to use my LinkStation for that, but this one is much quieter (no fan), and I don't need that much space. Will use SD as data FS, but you can stick a 2.5" HD inside it, it has mount points and internal SATA.

Comment: Wow, now I really want one...  Can it just be made to operate 100% from the internal sata drive?

Comment: Not sure, haven't played around enough with it yet. Check the docs, if you cant find them I can make a copy of the doc CD which came with mine. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to safely remove the `xorg-x11-server-*` and `xorg-x11-drv-*` packages, which are only used to run the X server itself. If you have no intention of ever connecting to it in order to run a graphical application then you can go as far down as `libX*` and `libxcb`.